# Double slit experiment and sensors/instruments influence

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality

In double-slit experiment, it is said when we turn on the sensor/detector/instrument to measure/detect the behaviour of the particle, it shows particle behaviour (otherwise, it shows wave behaviour).

I would like to know, how can we be sure this is not due to the influence/interaction/interference of our measurement, not necessarily the intrinsic nature of photons?

In most reference books, it seems it is a given and it is not discussed.

Comment: I mean , it is due to the impact of our measurement that the wave nature of an atom or quantum particle will collapse and  start behaving like a particle (maybe I'm not getting the question)

Comment: @KP99 I mean, any measurement affects the measured quantit. When we measure a voltage, we change the value which existed before measurement. Another example: if we have an extremely unstable system, any measurement will make the system collapse.

Comment: You may want to read just the beginning of the book Something Deeply Hidden by Sean Carroll. He describes nicely why textbooks do what they do. If we should therefore have to believe in the many worlds interpretation is of course another question.

Comment: You can repeat the same experiment with single photon and see that it is due to their intrinsic nature.... this video might help : https://youtu.be/I9Ab8BLW3kA

Comment: Individual photons travel through the slits and contribute to the fringe pattern. If you measure them, then essentially you are blocking those photons from getting to the screen and contributing to the pattern.

Comment: @Ebi, if you want to read about a version of the double-slit experiment that will REALLY "blow your mind", google "delayed choice quantum eraser".  That experiment doesn't have a detector at either slit but it gives the same results as all other double slit experiments.

Comment: @DavidWhite that’s a different situation. With no second beam splitter each detector receives photons from only ONE route. The upper or lower. With the second beam splitter in place each detector now receives photons from both routes and this creates the interference pattern.

Comment: @BillAlsept, ALL of the different versions of the double slit experiment are "a different situation".  Despite that, if you know which slit the photons went through, you get a particle result and if you don't know which slit the photons went through, you get a wave result.  In my opinion, this will happen no matter how you design the double slit experiment.

Answer (score 0):

The better question is to ask how the photons interacting with the edges of the obstacle.

On the one side we have a photon with its electric and magnetic field components. On the other side we have surface electrons on the edge with their charges and with their magnetic dipoles. How do they interact? Do plasmons or another surface excitons come into play?. If so, experiments with changing electric potential for the slits should show some results.

Never such experiments are done? They have bin done Witz electrons by Claus Jönsson and Gottfried Möllenstedt and dependent from the applied voltage the [intensity pattern on the screen changes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/206667/46708).

Comment: This answer does not seem to address the question of the OP.

Answer (score -2):

[Arrgh, fell into trap of answering a 2 year old question.  Well, the bot bumped it so I will leave my answer.]

> I would like to know, how can we be sure this is not due to the
> influence/interaction/interference of our measurement, not necessarily
> the intrinsic nature of photons?

Great question, and there is an exact answer to this.  You can place a polarizer in front of each slit (2 total polarizers), and orient them relative to each other.  If the loss of interference were a result of photons passing through or otherwise interacting with the polarizers, then no interference pattern would result.

But that is not what happens.  In actual experiments, it is the **relative** orientation of the 2 polarizers - and nothing else - that determines whether or not there is an interference pattern.  If the polarizers are parallel, there IS the usual interference pattern.  If the polarizers are perpendicular, there is NO interference pattern.  Either way, the total intensity of the pattern is the same.  See:

https://sciencedemonstrations.fas.harvard.edu/files/science-demonstrations/files/single_photon_paper.pdf

The general explanation is that if it is possible to learn the which slit information - even if it is not known - there will be no interference.  You *could* learn it by checking photon polarization.  That polarization becomes a sort of marker, as explained in the paper.

*"Even if not actually measured, the mere possibility that an observer could determine which slit the photon passed through causes the interference pattern to switch to non-interference."*

Obviously, it is not the interaction with the polarizer that is the variable here.  So yes, this is a property of quantum particles such as photons.