# What is the maximum distance between slits in Young's experiment?

Tags: double-slit-experiment

For example, if the distance between the slits is a 1 light year, would there be a non-zero probability that an electron would pass through one of the slits and leave an interference pattern?

Comment: The electrons making the interference pattern pass through both slits.

Comment: The interference pattern is a probability distribution. There is no such thing as the probability of a single detection event to leave a probability distribution. Also, with a single detection event there is no way of knowing which probability distribution is applicable.

Comment: For the Fraunhofer limit to apply the source of the electron must be much further away than the slit distance. The wavelength of the electron should be of the order of a lightyear so it would take quite some time before the electron would arrive a your slit system. Hundreds of billions of years. You should use light instead.

Comment: If you only have one slit, and even if you only use one wire ([bi-prism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/206667)) and even if you only have one edge, you will see an intensity distribution on an observation screen. Even if you release the electrons individually onto the object. The question then naturally arises as to whether a double slit is not simply the concerted sum of the individual interactions.

Answer (score 1):

There is in theory no maximum distance between the slits. However, there are two practical considerations which make the observation of an electron interference pattern more difficult with very widely spaced slits:

1. The spacing between the fringes of the interference pattern is proportional to the wavelength of the electrons, with the constant of proportionality being the ratio of the distance between the slits and the screen to the separation of the slits. So a large slit separation requires a correspondingly large distance between the slits and the screen in order to create a visible interference pattern.
2. The greater the distance between the slits and the screen, the more likely it is that an electron will interact with something along one of its possible paths to the screen. This will destroy the superposition of states for that electron, so it no longer contributes to the interference pattern. If a high proportion of electrons interact before they reach the screen then it becomes more and more difficult to distinguish the interference pattern from background noise.